# Apache Flink - Does DataSet API Support Writing Output to Individual File Partitions

Tags: apache-flink, parquet

I am using the Dataset API with Flink and I am trying to partition parquet files by a key in my POJO e.g. date. The end goal is to write my files down using the following file structure.

```
/output/
    20180901/
        file.parquet
    20180902/
        file.parquet
```

Flink provides a convenience class to wrap  `AvroParquetOutputFormat` as shown below but I don't see anyway to provide a partitioning key.

```
HadoopOutputFormat<Void, Pojo> outputFormat = 
    new HadoopOutputFormat(new AvroParquetOutputFormat(), Job.getInstance());
```

I'm trying to figure out the best way to proceed. Do I need to write my own version of `AvroParquetOutputFormat` that extends hadoops `MultipleOutputs` type or can I leverage the Flink APIs to do this for me.

The equivalent in Spark would be.

```
df.write.partitionBy('date').parquet('base path')
```

Comment: if u find any solution for this please help me with the same .

Comment: I decided to use Spark. My productivity was more important.

Comment: Hi, could you please give me a hint how to convert my DataSet[MyType] -> DataSet[Void,MyType]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `BucketingSink<T>` sink to write data in partitions you defined by supplying an instance of the `Bucketer` interface. See the DateTimeBucketer for an example. 
https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-connectors/flink-connector-filesystem/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/fs/DateTimeBucketer.java